# Windows 7 - replaced partition icon - issue

Tags: windows, windows-7, windows-xp

The icon for my C: drive in Windows 7 has changed but I don't know why. I can't remember the last thing I've installed, so I'm not sure what might have caused this.

Is this dangerous? How can I fix it? I can also see it in Windows XP.

[image]

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=878475

Answer (score 1):

Check `C:\Autorun.inf`.

Comment: [autorun]
OPEN=
ICON=\SMRTNTKY\fcw.ico
ACTION=Kreator sieci bezprzewodowej - what means creator of wirelles

Comment: The `ICON=` line sets the icon.

Comment: Is it a virus? It creates SMRTNTKY folder, and i delete it.

Comment: @GabrielŻukowski: No; it's Wireless Network Setup Wizard.  http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=878475